# Left join is returning multiple rows from Table B corresponding to ID present in Table A

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my SQL database. Let's call them Table A and Table B. 
I have joined both the tables using left join on ID = AID. Table A has a field by name ID and Table B has field AID and Price. 
The problem is Table B can have multiple prices for the ID present in Table A.

The requirement is - If only one price is present in Table B corresponding to ID in table A then it should return that price. 
If more than one price is present in table B for an ID in table A then I should get the price as Zero/null.

Query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,B.Price 
  from A 
  left join B 
  on A.ID = B.AID 
  where "some condition"
```

Comment: Mysql or sql.server .. please remove the improper tag ..

Answer (score 1):

Use `Count()` with `Over()` window function to find the count of records for each `ID` then based on count return the `price`

Try this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,
      case when count(1) over(partition by A.ID) > 1 then NULL else B.Price end
from A 
left join B 
on A.ID = B.AID
```

For `Mysql`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN c.aid IS NULL THEN NULL 
                  ELSE b.price 
                END 
FROM   a 
       LEFT JOIN b 
              ON a.id = b.aid 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT aid 
                  FROM   b 
                  GROUP  BY aid 
                  HAVING Count(1) = 1) c 
              ON a.id = c.aid
```

Comment: When i 'm using the above in my query i'm getting syntax error near Over.

Comment: @ashish - You are using `Mysql` or `Sql Server`

Comment: sorry its mysql and i forgot to tell you that initially i was using inner query , the same that you have suggested. But it is taking longtime in executing on android 5.0 and 6.0 but same works fine on android 4.4. So i tried with join and it is taking normal time in executing, just that my requirement is not getting fulfilled. So i have posted this query. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server** (should work for **MySQL** too). One sub-query (you can put in CTE) that shows only `AID`s that have only one price:

```
SELECT  A.ID,
        B.Price
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT AID
        FROM B
        GROUP BY AID
        HAVING COUNT(Price) = 1
    ) as C
    ON C.AID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN B 
    ON C.AID = B.AID
```

Comment: well since the op can't upvote, I will upvote both you 2 guys

Comment: @Drew thanks, for testing (I checked on SQL Server only) and voting up!

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. It should work.

```
SELECT  A.ID, o.Price  
FROM    A  
OUTER APPLY  
        (  
            SELECT  IIF(COUNT(B.Price)>1,NULL,MAX(B.Price)) AS Price  
            FROM    B
            WHERE   B.AID = A.ID  
        ) AS o;
```

[image: Screenshot]